# Speed up Eclipse over X server

Tags: linux, windows, solaris, eclipse, xserver

In my job we have tight security rules, so the development environment is all virtualized. Each developer has a workstation with Windows XP and Citrix Metaframe. From the Metaframe, the developer opens a remote desktop to Solaris on SPARC. And in there, from the terminal, he sshs into one of several remote Linux machines with shared filesystems and works there. The Linux machines have no desktop system, so most people use `vim` for coding. (This starts sounding like an article to TheDailyWTF already.)

The developers must use the Linux machines, because they are the only ones with IBM ClearCase installed (they can't see their code in Windows or Solaris). Fortunately, the Solaris has an X server, so people can at least use `gvim`. When I installed Eclipse in Linux, it runs OK over the X server, but the refresh performance is sluggish. I need to wait several seconds for every repaint (which renders the Eclipse unusable). I already know that the network bandwidth is not an issue, all machines have several Mbits between them.

I'm not a Linux expert, so I reached my debugging limits on this. Linuxes have Java 6, Solaris is 10 with CDE. I already tried setting `-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false`, but that does not help. The `gvim` has repaint issues as well (but is still usable). I also installed `Xming` on the Windows machine and used PuTTY to remote into the Linux boxes, but the repaint performance was even worse. How can I pinpoint the problem so that I can ask sysadmins to fix it?

UPDATE: We have also QtCreator IDE installed, and it works like a charm over both Xming and Solaris X server. So maybe it's a Java issue?

Comment: It really reads a bit like a DailyWTF

Comment: Frankly your whole environment sounds like the problem - I would start by taking a big, clean sheet of paper and designing something that's not quite so terribly convoluted.  If that's not an option I have no idea where to even begin in untangling this knot.